# Re-assembling mdadm RAID1

Tags: mdadm

I was in the process of reinstalling from Mint 18 -> 20.

I have 2x 4TB devices RAID1'ed with mdadm. One of them had degraded/dropped off the array for some reason. (Not sure if this happens for any other reason besides HDD going bad?) Hence I decided to make sure my RAID array is up-to-date before I reinstall and add them to the new system.

I added the spare device to array with

```
mdadm /dev/md0 --add /dev/sdf
```

I was actually supposed to use `--add /dev/sdf1` as there was partition on the drive. Was this also a mistake, or does it make any difference?

Then I blundered and accidentally rebooted while `mdadm` was rebuilding, which caused the `/dev/md0` to fail. I had to remove `/dev/md0` from `fstab` in order to properly boot.

```
mdadm --examine /dev/sdc1
```

Shows

```
Update Time : Sun Jan  5 03:32:11 2020
```

which means it should be the spare device.

Likewise `/dev/sdb1` has

```
Update Time : Thu Feb 25 02:38:37 2021
```

indicating it's the main drive.

How should I proceed to reassemble this back to `/dev/md0` so that `sdb1`, having the latest data, is mirrored to `sdc1`? I'd assume something like

```
mdadm --assemble --verbose --run /dev/md0 /dev/sdb1 /dev/sdc1
```

but I want to make sure it should be ok to run this without risk of losing data.

Or should I perhaps just run the command without `/dev/sdc1` and only add the one drive that is up-to-date and known to be working?

Superblock infos:

```
/dev/sdb1:
          Magic : a92b4efc
        Version : 1.2
    Feature Map : 0x1
     Array UUID : b2c183f1:793b927a:17534194:5f000d8c
           Name : rattletrap:0  (local to host rattletrap)
  Creation Time : Mon Oct 16 07:41:56 2017
     Raid Level : raid1
   Raid Devices : 2

 Avail Dev Size : 7813772943 (3725.90 GiB 4000.65 GB)
     Array Size : 3906886464 (3725.90 GiB 4000.65 GB)
  Used Dev Size : 7813772928 (3725.90 GiB 4000.65 GB)
    Data Offset : 262144 sectors
   Super Offset : 8 sectors
   Unused Space : before=262056 sectors, after=15 sectors
          State : clean
    Device UUID : 69317f2c:1a988f46:26f00a3a:b2d4ba14

Internal Bitmap : 8 sectors from superblock
    Update Time : Thu Feb 25 02:38:37 2021
  Bad Block Log : 512 entries available at offset 72 sectors
       Checksum : 6c26dd58 - correct
         Events : 57352

   Device Role : Active device 0
   Array State : AA ('A' == active, '.' == missing, 'R' == replacing)



/dev/sdc1:
          Magic : a92b4efc
        Version : 1.2
    Feature Map : 0x1
     Array UUID : b2c183f1:793b927a:17534194:5f000d8c
           Name : rattletrap:0  (local to host rattletrap)
  Creation Time : Mon Oct 16 07:41:56 2017
     Raid Level : raid1
   Raid Devices : 2

 Avail Dev Size : 7813772943 (3725.90 GiB 4000.65 GB)
     Array Size : 3906886464 (3725.90 GiB 4000.65 GB)
  Used Dev Size : 7813772928 (3725.90 GiB 4000.65 GB)
    Data Offset : 262144 sectors
   Super Offset : 8 sectors
   Unused Space : before=262056 sectors, after=15 sectors
          State : clean
    Device UUID : f6ccc9b9:0fa3652d:61d1898a:504c2462

Internal Bitmap : 8 sectors from superblock
    Update Time : Sun Jan  5 03:32:11 2020
  Bad Block Log : 512 entries available at offset 72 sectors
       Checksum : 7c0c6339 - correct
         Events : 7041


   Device Role : Active device 1
   Array State : AA ('A' == active, '.' == missing, 'R' == replacing)
```

Answer (score 1):

All went good by

> mdadm --stop /dev/md0

And then

> mdadm /dev/md0 --assemble /dev/sdb1 /dev/sdc1